# How to kill all threads before Application terminate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Sometimes my app (for OS X) is crashing if I terminate it with Cmd+Q command. I use BOOST library. Crash Report shows me that there is a 6 threads. And I think that some threads can't stop and this cause crash.

Is there some way to get the list of all runing threads and stop them one by one and only after that close the App?

Comment: Stacktrace and debug before you make any assumptions. It helps you locate the code which causes the crash.

Comment: What's the crash signal/exception? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: “And I think that some threads can't stop and this cause crash.” Nope. If the threads don't stop, your app will hang, not crash. Please edit your question to include the crash log, as it will show where the crash occurred.

Comment: Actually, what I said above is untrue: If the main thread exits (whether by `main` returning or by a `-[NSApplication terminate:]` message), the program will exit immediately. It won't even hang for other threads. No crash, no hang. At any rate, the crash is caused by something else, and only the crash log can make any progress at revealing what.